# iOS9: configure spotlight news suggestions

Tags: spotlight, ios

When I swipe left from the first page of my home screen, iOS 9 brings me to the spotlight screen.

There I can see Siri suggestions and news.
Is there a way to configure which news are showed in this page?

Note: I do not have the news app, I suppose because it is not yet available in all the countries.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: As of iOS 10 you can remove the news widget.

It is not possible in iOS 9. See this question for more information about turning all/news suggestions off. [Removing news headlines from Spotlight Search in iOS 9](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206080/removing-news-headlines-from-spotlight-search/206181#206181)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your region to USA from settings.app to use news app

Comment: Could you add a screen shot of this? You might be on to a solution on customizing this for many.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to "configure" the spotlight suggestions for the news.
You can only disable it altogether from Settings/General/Spotlight search.

All I get are news from NY Times, CNN, Washington Post.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Language and Region in General settings and set it to your region.